# Change Identity Of Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How can change the current identity of a table to a new identity.
Please help me to work this.

Comment: Are you talking about changing the identity column, or changing the current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about [reseeding the identity](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/)?

From the article:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change which column has the IDENTITY property. While Management Studio will make you think you can do this, it's actually not doing this at all - behind the scenes it is dropping your table and re-creating it for you. Here is how you can drop the current identity column and add a new one, though keep in mind this gives you absolutely no control over how the new identity values are assigned:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo DROP COLUMN current_identity_column;
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD new_identity_column INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```